# how to add 1place code Google Analytic

Tags: php, google-analytics

Google Analytic Experience Users

I have 4sites(domain)

Ex: **Site1**, **Site2**, **Site3** and **MainSite** ( for the Sourcecode is in **MainSite** only )

I want to add Google Analytic Code into **MainSite**

Does it possible to get to know traffic from another 3 sites (**Site1**, **Site2**, **Site3**) ?

Please don't mind my question?

Answer (score 0):

You may find a good explanation here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite?hl=EN#multipleDomains

There are many scenarios with examples that seem to be just your case.

Although, you will probably need to use PHP to print the current domain on the appropriate place in the analytics code.

Comment: Oh, you mean that try to get the current domain and switch it with analytic code right?

Comment: _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '<?php echo $domain; ?>']);